# Spark - most frequent word following a given word

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am learning Scala and I am trying to figure out how to create a MapReduce program in Scala to find, for each word in the file which word that follows the most. 
this is what I have. it works but I want to actually use map reduce and I am trying to find ways to reduce looping as much as possible

```
 //initialize the list with first two words
  val list = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList((words.collect()(0), 
    words.collect()(1)));

   for (x <- 1 to (words.collect().length - 2)) {
  // add element into the list
  list += ((words.collect()(x), words.collect()(x + 1)))
   }
val rdd1 = spark.parallelize(list)

val rdd2 = rdd1.map(word => (word, 1)) // ex: key is (basketball,is)  value is 1

val counter = rdd2.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y).sortBy(_._2, false) // sort in dec

val result2 = counter.collect();

print("the most frequent follower for basketball, the, and competitive \n")

println(" ")

// calls the function

findFreq("basketball", result2)

findFreq("the", result2)

findFreq("competitive", result2)

  }

 // method to find the most frequent follower for the specific word
   def findFreq(str: String, RDD: Array[((String, String), (Int))]): Unit = 
{

var max = -1;

for (x <- RDD) {
  }

  // display the results
  if (x._1._1.equals(str) && x._2 == max) {
    println("\"" + x._1._1 + "\"" + " is followed by " + "\"" + x._1._2 + "\"" + " " + x._2 + " times.\n")
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of words (as a RDD), you can get the most frequent word that follows a given `word` in a few transformations:

**Step 1**: a RDD of word-pairs using [sliding(2)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions@sliding(windowSize:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[T]])

```
  .sliding(2)
```

**Step 2**: a pair-RDD with `(word, w2)` as key, then `reduceByKey` to count occurrences of word-pairs of the given `word`

```
  .collect{ case Array(`word`, w2) => ((word, w2), 1) }
  .reduceByKey( _ + _ )
```

**Step 3**: a pair-RDD with `word` as key, then `reduceByKey` to capture word pairs with max count

```
  .map{ case ((`word`, w2), c) => (word, (w2, c)) }
  .reduceByKey( (acc, x) => if (x._2 > acc._2) (x._1, x._2) else acc )
```

Putting everything altogether with the transformations wrapped in a method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

// load a RDD of words from the text file
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/basketball.txt")
  .flatMap( _.split("""[\s,.;:!?]+""") )
  .map( _.toLowerCase )

def mostFreq(word: String, rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[(String, (String, Int))] =
  rdd
    .sliding(2)
    .collect{ case Array(`word`, w2) => ((word, w2), 1) }
    .reduceByKey( _ + _ )
    .map{ case ((`word`, w2), c) => (word, (w2, c)) }
    .reduceByKey( (acc, x) => if (x._2 > acc._2) (x._1, x._2) else acc )
```

Display the most frequent word that follows a given `word`:

```
mostFreq("basketball", rdd).foreach{ case (word, (w2, c)) =>
  println(s"'$word' is followed most frequently by '$w2' for $c times. ")
}
// 'basketball' is followed most frequently by 'leagues' for 2 times.
```

Sample text file: /path/to/basketball.txt (content from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball)):

> Basketball is one of the world's most popular and widely viewed
>   sports. The National Basketball Association (NBA) is one of the most
>   significant professional basketball leagues in the world in terms of
>   popularity, salaries, talent, and level of competition. Outside North
>   America, the top clubs from national basketball leagues qualify to
>   continental championships such as the Euroleague and FIBA Americas
>   League. The FIBA Basketball World Cup and Men's Olympic Basketball
>   Tournament are the major international events of the sport and attract
>   top national teams from around the world.